# How matching data is retrieved from two different db results in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, yii

I am new to laravel.I have two DB results which are stored in 2 different variables.But i want to know how matching records are fetched from these 2 results.

```
$cRes = ModelA::all();
$sRes  = ModelB::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate();
$data = $sRes->cRes->pluck('name') ;
```

Result of $sRes

```
  $sRes=Array( [id] =>1,
           [name] =>TEST1);
```

Result of $cRes

```
$cRes = Array([id] => 4,
              [name] => PHP);
```

Final result

```
  $data = PHP
```

I want to how $data is retrieved

Answer (score 0):

Make a relationship between ModelA & ModelB

In Model A:

```
function modelb(){
    ...
}
```

In Model B:

```
function modela(){
    ...
}
```

Then in query

```
$data = ModelA::with('modelb')->select('name')->get();
```